# Java split String in three parts

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split String into 3 parts. 
Example:

```
String s="a [Title: title] [Content: content]";
```

Result should be:

```
s[0]="a"; 
s[1]="Title: title"; 
s[2]="Content: content";
```

Later I would like to put Title: title and Content: content in a Map as String key-value pair.

Comment: The parsing here is complex.  If you can change the format of the string such that it looks like this: `a;Title:title;Content:content`, then this would be much easier.  Otherwise, I recommend finding this guy: http://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
String s = "a [Title: title] [Content: content]";
String parts[] = s.split("\\]?\\s*\\[|\\]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**OR**

```
String s = "a [Title: title] [Content: content]";
String parts[] = s.split("\\s(?![^\\[\\]]*\\])");  # Splits the input according to spaces which are not present inside the square brackets
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String i: parts)                              # iterate over the array list elements.
{
    l.add(i.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));           # replace all [, ] chars from the list elements and append it to the declared list l
}
System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

```
[a, Title: title, Content: content]
```